# Tentando aplicar um degrade dentro de uma série no amcharts V3

Tags: javascript, json

Estou tentando montar um gráfico no amcharts 3 onde maior parte das configurações são definidas no JSON do gráfico, porém eu preciso efetuar um degrade na série, em outras palavras, preciso fazer um gráfico assim:

[Chart a ser efetuado](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjb26.png)

Alguém sabe como posso fazer?

Este é o meu JSON:

{
"type": "serial",
"color": "#686A6A",
"language": "pt",
"export": {
"enabled": true
},
"categoryField": "cunho",
"startDuration": 1,
"categoryAxis": {
"gridPosition": "start",
"axisAlpha": 0,
"gridAlpha": 0
},
"graphs": [
{
"balloonText": "Valor da causa 
**R$ [[valorcausa]]** \n Valor previsto para desembolso 
**R$ [[valorprevisto]]**",
"id": "AmGraph-1",
"labelText": "[[value]]",
"title": "Quantidade de processos",
"alphaField": "fill_alpha_field",
"valueField": "qtdeprocessos",
"type": "column",
"fillAlphas": 1,
"fillColors": "#105730",
"lineColor": "#105730",
"bulletColor": "#105730"
}
],
"valueAxes": [
{
"id": "ValueAxis-1",
"title": "",
"axisAlpha": 0,
"gridAlpha": 0,
"labelsEnabled": false
}
],
"balloon": {
"pointerOrientation": "right",
"color": "#FFFFFF",
"fillColor": "#000000"
},
"legend": {
"enabled": true,
"position": "bottom",
"useGraphSettings": true
},
"version": "3",
"rotate": true,
"theme4": "frozen",
"theme": "default"
}

Comment: As linhas estão sorteadas por qual atributo?  Mostra o exemplo do json..

Comment: @ruansenadev prontinho, acabei esquecendo de colocar o json antes, mas coloquei agora.

Answer (score 0):

Como o degradê que você deseja é em partes de cores sólidas e não é em gradiente, é necessário variar a luminosidade da cor, para criar uma efeito de degradê linear.

No AmCharts5 já tem essa possibilidade com a propriedade `brigthnesses`, no qual você passa uma variante pra cada coluna. Com AmCharts3 é necessário um `plugin` pra funcionar:

```js
// Declaração do plugin
/**
 * AmCharts plugin: Auto-calculate color based on value
 * The plugin relies on custom chart propety: `colorRanges`
 */
AmCharts.addInitHandler(function(chart) {

  var dataProvider = chart.dataProvider;
  var colorRanges = chart.colorRanges;

  // Based on https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-generate-lighter-darker-color/
  function ColorLuminance(hex, lum) {

    // validate hex string
    hex = String(hex).replace(/[^0-9a-f]/gi, '');
    if (hex.length < 6) {
      hex = hex[0] + hex[0] + hex[1] + hex[1] + hex[2] + hex[2];
    }
    lum = lum || 0;

    // convert to decimal and change luminosity
    var rgb = "#",
      c, i;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      c = parseInt(hex.substr(i * 2, 2), 16);
      c = Math.round(Math.min(Math.max(0, c + (c * lum)), 255)).toString(16);
      rgb += ("00" + c).substr(c.length);
    }

    return rgb;
  }

  if (colorRanges) {

    var item;
    var range;
    var valueProperty;
    var value;
    var average;
    var variation;
    for (var i = 0, iLen = dataProvider.length; i < iLen; i++) {

      item = dataProvider[i];

      for (var x = 0, xLen = colorRanges.length; x < xLen; x++) {

        range = colorRanges[x];
        valueProperty = range.valueProperty;
        value = item[valueProperty];

        if (value >= range.start && value <= range.end) {
          average = (range.start - range.end) / 2;

          if (value <= average)
            variation = (range.variation * -1) / value * average;
          else if (value > average)
            variation = range.variation / value * average;

          item[range.colorProperty] = ColorLuminance(range.color, variation.toFixed(2));
        }
      }
    }
  }

}, ["serial"]);

var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "light",
  // O plugin requer o seguinte objeto para definir as cores em um set de dados:
  "colorRanges": [
    {
      // o valor inicial do set, correspondente a "valueProperty"
      "start": 0,
      // o valor até o qual queres cobrir no set, com a cor variante
      "end": 2500,
      // a cor base
      "color": "#015c55",
      // Variação da luminosidade, brilho(negativo) ou escurecimento(positivo)
      "variation": -0.5,
      // Propriedade do set de dados que será usado no plugin (ex: "qtdeprocessos")
      "valueProperty": "visits",
      // A propriedade na qual tá sendo aplicada a cor variante
      "colorProperty": "color"
    }
    // também é possivel adicionar mais outra cor para outro set de dados aqui
  ],
  "dataProvider": [{
    "country": "USA",
    "visits": 2025
  }, {
    "country": "Japan",
    "visits": 1809
  }, {
    "country": "UK",
    "visits": 1122
  }, {
    "country": "India",
    "visits": 984
  }, {
    "country": "Netherlands",
    "visits": 665
  }, {
    "country": "South Korea",
    "visits": 443
  }, {
    "country": "Brazil",
    "visits": 395
  }],
  "valueAxes": [{
    "gridColor": "#FFFFFF",
    "gridAlpha": 0.2,
    "dashLength": 0
  }],
  "gridAboveGraphs": true,
  "startDuration": 1,
  "graphs": [{
    "balloonText": "[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b>",
    "fillAlphas": 0.8,
    "lineAlpha": 0.2,
    "type": "column",
    "valueField": "visits",
    "colorField": "color"
  }],
  "chartCursor": {
    "categoryBalloonEnabled": false,
    "cursorAlpha": 0,
    "zoomable": false
  },
  "categoryField": "country",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "gridPosition": "start",
    "gridAlpha": 0,
    "tickPosition": "start",
    "tickLength": 20
  },
  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  }

});
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

#chartdiv {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>

<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

fontes: [amCharts3 Docs](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v3/tutorials/auto-calculate-column-color-based-value/)